# Help understanding the unique property of limits.

Tags: real-analysis

The proof goes:

If $(p_n)$ converges to $p$ if $(p_n)$ also converges to $p'$ then $p = p'$. Given any $\epsilon > 0$, there are integers $N, N'$ such that if $n \ge N$ then $d(p_n, p) < \epsilon$, while if $n \ge N'$ then $d(p_n, p') < \epsilon$.

Now, here is where I get stuck. The proof continues by saying:

Then for all $n \ge \max \{N, N' \}$, $d(p,p') \le d(p,p_n) + d(p_n, p') < \epsilon + \epsilon  = 2 \epsilon$. But $\epsilon$ is arbitrary and so $d(p,p') = 0$ and $p=p'$.

Comment: Is there an actual question? Regards

Answer (score 4):

The distance function $d$ enjoys the property that $d(x,y) = 0$ if and only if $x=y$. That is, distinct points are a positive distance apart, and every point is zero distance from itself. So to show that $p=p'$, it is equivalent to show that $d(p,p') = 0$. This reduces to showing that $d(p,p') < \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon > 0$. This is what the final step of the proof is showing.

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer your question, but here is another version of the proof that $p=p'$.

Suppose to the contrary that $p\ne p'$. Let $\epsilon=d(p,p')$.

By the definition of limit, there is and $N$ such that if $n\ge N$ then $d(p_n,p)\lt \epsilon/3$.

By the definition of limit, there is and $N'$ such that if $n\ge N'$ then $d(p_n,p')\lt \epsilon/3$.

Let $M=\max(N,N')$. Then if $n\ge M$ we have simultaneously $d(p_n,p)\lt \epsilon/3$ and $d(p_n,p')\lt \epsilon/3$.

But then by the Triangle Inequality $d(p,p')\lt 2\epsilon/3$, contradicting the fact that $d(p,p')=\epsilon$.